# Sending a call to facebook graph api does not return anything when an error occurs

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I am using graph api to get a list of albums of a user. Now in case the user signs out or has changes password or any error condition, I do not get any response whereas some error code should be returned. The graph API url when opened in the browser shows the error but on using file_get_contents() i get error 400. On using curl, I get an empty response. Is there any way that I can find out when an error occurs and the reason for it?

Answer (score 0):

> The graph API url when opened in the browser shows the error but on using file_get_contents() i get error 400.

Well, that is the HTTP status code that Facebook sends with Oauth errors – nothing wrong about that.

But `file_get_contents` by default does **not** show you the actual HTTP response body content in case of an HTTP status codes that signals an error …

… which is just another reason, why one should use the official PHP SDK, which handles all of that nicely and presents you with an exception that tells you exactly what is up.

So do it, please.

---

(Even with `file_get_contents` one can get the body content of the response, when setting a “stream context” with the according option first. But using the PHP SDK is way simpler, so again: Please do it.)

Answer (score 0):

I used curl instead of file_get_contents and the issue got resolved.

Answer (score -1):

file_get_contents() gave me error many times when I put https instead of http or If I forgot to put any of them.

Your URL from which you get the content must have "http" at the starting, like:

file_get_contents("**http**://www.mysite.com");

If this solves it?

Comment: Downvote it everybody, I just shared what I had the problem in my case, Cmon down-vote my-profile too.....